# OctoberCMS - Overridden Blog Component (Rainlab Blog) Multiple Usage in Same Page

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, twig-extension

I am new to OctoberCMS and I am stuck now, I am facing issue to use my custom blog posts component (which overrides Rainlab blog posts) in the same page multiple times.

Say I have created an alias of default **blogPosts** to **postLists** and I defined my custom HTML structure and it is working well, no issues.

Now what I want is to use the **postLists** post structure in my page for three different categories and here I am stuck because when I pass variable to component like this - `{ % component 'postLists' categoryFilter='news' %}` it does not work for the category filter and if I select a category from drag drop component UI it becomes global categoryFilter setting for the page.

[image: screenshot]

This is my requirement.

[image: requirements]

My postList component code:-

```
{% set posts = __SELF__.posts %}
{% for post in posts %}

<div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-4 content_body_img">
            <a href="{{ post.url }}">
        {% if post.featured_images.count > 0 %}
            <img class="media-object" src="{{ post.featured_images.first.getThumb(108, 108) }}" />
        {% else %}
            <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/108x108" />
        {% endif %}
    </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-8">
          <p><a href="{{ post.url }}">{{ post.title }}</a></p>
          <!--location_date-->
          <div class="location_date">
            <ul>
              <li><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i><span> {{ post.published_at|date('j F, Y') }}<span></li>
              <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Dubai</li>
            </ul>
          </div>
          <!--location_date end -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--content_body_img end -->
{% else %}
<div class="col-sm-6 col-6 col-lg-3">{{ noPostsMessage }}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Please help me, any help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks Sanny

Comment: Please post component code

Comment: @NileshYadav added component code

Comment: Also please post component php

Answer (score 0):

### This is static Approach - I will post dynamic Approach as well give me some time

Best and possibly easy solution will be ( in case you just intend to show posts ) is to add `3 Post List component` with `Different Category filter` option for each tab.

[image]

It should do your work

> make sure this is optimal solution if you just need to show lists nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for your time and response, this was the first thing hit in my mind but I can not use this method because I have created a partial (which overrides default blogPosts partial html) for blogPosts and its alias is postList (blogPostsFood in your example), if I change alias I can not use my custom post loop structure. Please let me know if it make sense to you or you have a solution for this senario.

Comment: yes i got that too so checking if we can make it dynamic Approach

Comment: any luck @Hardik?

Comment: sorry i tried but no luck, I need to work on it but no time at the moment :(